# How to show specific data from database only once?

Tags: java, android, sql, database

How to get variables `text1`, `text2` and `time` to show only once, on the beginning, like *title*, because they have same values for specific group of data, and then below to show variable `text3` as many time as that variable have values for that specific group of data.

When `text3` finish with writing data, for that group of data, query must start to write another group of data for `text1`, `text2` and `time` and new values of `text3` below.

This is my code:

```
 public class NapredakActivity extends Activity {  
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.first);
 String var;
 final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 var=intent.getStringExtra("date");
       SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Database", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       String q = "SELECT text1 ,text2, text3, time FROM table WHERE time LIKE '"+var+"'";

       Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);

       if( c.getCount() < 1 ){

           c.close();
           db.close();
           Toast.makeText(NapredakActivity.this, "wrong choice",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           startActivity(new Intent(this,calendar.class));
       }
       else{
                 String j="";
                                           c.moveToFirst();
                         do {
                          String cm = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text1" )); 
                          String cm2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text2"));            
                          String cm4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text3"));
                          String cm3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time" ));

                        j = j+"\n"+cm+cm4+cm2+cm3;  

                          } while (c.moveToNext());

                         t.setText(j);   
                   c.close();
              db.close();        
       }        }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly assuming you like to keep the way you show the db content, ie in one single TextView, just use a flag like this:

```
else{
                         String cmOld ="a text that never will be in the BD";
                         boolean flag_newText1Found;
                         String j="";
                         c.moveToFirst();
                         do {
                          String cm = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text1" )); 
                          if (cm.equals(cmOld)) 
                             cm = "";
                          else
                             cmOld = cm;
                          String cm2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text2"));            
                          String cm4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text3"));
                          String cm3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time" ));

                        j = j+"\n"+cm+cm4+cm2+cm3;  

                          } while (c.moveToNext());


                         t.setText(j);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I apply this code, nothing happens. Output is the same. What did you mean with "a text that never will be in the BD", boolean flag_newText1Found. What does that means?